# How to specify the row height in LaTeX table?

Tags: tables

I want to create a LaTeX table with three rows which have different row heights.
How can I do this?

The following code

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.4} \setlength\minrowclearance{2.4pt}
```

seems make each row has the same height.

Comment: you could probably use \rule{0pt}{<lenght>} to create a line with 0 width but a certain vertical length.

Comment: I obtain an error that `\minrowclearance` is an undefined control sequence. Do you need to load a package?

Comment: @Karlo \usepackage{colortbl}

Answer (score 85):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
hi & tall one\\[10ex]
\hline
hi & medium one\\[5ex]
\hline
hi & standard one\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So you can specify the height of a row with the optional argument

Comment: how do you vertically centralize the elements in a cell, using the [ex] optional argument?!

Comment: Using `\\[<space>]` adds space to the end of the last cell, so if the last cell of each row has significantly different contents, then the row height can vary. This is easily solved by adding an extra column, and keeping it empty. Then `\\[<space>]` always makes the row `<space>` as a minimum.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley This won't help when you have hlines as then adding an additional column will produce extra lines at the end. Additionally, it still keeps the contents vertically spaced near the top rather than within the cell in the center vertically

Comment: @AramPapazian This can be fixed by using columns like `{cc@{}c@{}}` as the `@{}` will make the space either side of the empty column 0 pt.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley you wrote "Then `\\[<space>]` always makes the row `<space>` as a minimum." but this is not what happens. If I replace your tabular with the following, `\begin{tabular}{cc} 1 & \\[0mm] 2 & \\[5mm] \end{tabular}` the first row is 4.36mm high while the second measures 9.36mm. The 5mm goes into some equation but it's not the minimum height when leaving the last column blank.

Answer (score 12):

As none of the current answers address the issue of how to **center** the content vertically, I here introduce `\xrowht[<footprint>]{<length>}` to add an e**x**tra `.5<length>` of height above and below a `\vphantom` of a `<footprint>`.  The default footprint takes the height of a `0` character, which is great if the data has no descenders.  For data with descenders, an optionally specified footprint of `()` makes more sense.

`\xrowht` can be added to any cell in the row.  Here, I add it to the 1st column cells, for convenience.

In the MWE, the 1st row is unmodified, then for successive rows, 10pt, 20pt, 30pt, and 40pt are symmetrically added.  I also use an optional footprint in the 2nd row, which contains descenders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
      \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
        \hline
         col1 & col2 \\
        \hline\xrowht[()]{10pt}
        1 & 2g \\
        \hline\xrowht{20pt}
        3 & 4 \\
        \hline\xrowht{30pt}
        5 & 6 \\
        \hline\xrowht{40pt}
        7 & 8 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I extend the first row? Just natively adding `\xrowht{20pt}` afterr the first `\hline` results in `\xrowht{20pt}`...

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error:
... it results in `main.tex|56 error| Misplaced \noalign. 
main.tex|56 error| Misplaced \omit. `

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
      \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
        \hline\xrowht{20pt}
         col1 & col2 \\
        \hline\xrowht[()]{10pt}
        1 & 2g \\
        \hline\xrowht{20pt}
        3 & 4 \\
        \hline\xrowht{30pt}
        5 & 6 \\
        \hline\xrowht{40pt}
        7 & 8 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}` works for me @Theova

Comment: Right, the problem is with including multicol:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
    \xrowht{20pt}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ multicol } \\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt} col1 & col2 \\
    \hline\xrowht[()]{10pt} 1 & 2g \\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt} 3 & 4 \\
    \hline\xrowht{30pt} 5 & 6 \\
    \hline\xrowht{40pt} 7 & 8 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Theova Move the `\xrowht` macrow *inside* the `\multicolumn`, such as `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \xrowht{20pt} multicol } \\ `

Comment: @ Steven: Thank you very much. This works as desired :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of "[()]" right next to those 10pt??

Comment: @CristianBaeza The `[]` specify, in LaTeX grammar, an optional argument to a macro, in this case `\xrowht`.  The actual value of that optional argument is `()`.  In this macro, the optional argument is added as a `\vphantom` to the table cell.  That is to say, it becomes part of the vertical footprint inside the cell.  I just happen to know that all font letters will always fit within the vertical footprint of `()`.  If you remove it from the 1st row, you will see the cell shorten at the bottom.  Because the row data contains a descending character `g`, the vertical balance would be thrown off

Comment: The command is very useful, but how can I automatically avoid that annoying spacing generated right before the elements in the first column? I've noticed that numbers 1,3,5,7 are not horizontally centered in the generated table and I'm having the same problem in my document, any ideas?

Comment: This only vertically centers the first column for me...

Comment: @Vinz Is your column content simple text on a single row, as in my example, or does your content naturally contain more complex vertical components, such as super/sub-scripting and or multi-row content?

Answer (score 4):

It is easy peasy to set row heights and get perfect middle alignment for multirow cells with new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{M}[1]{Q[m,c,#1]}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={M{3cm}M{3.5cm}M{3.5cm}},row{2-4}={7ex}}
  \hline
    Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
  \hline 
    \SetCell[r=3]{c} Text & Text & Text \\
  \hline
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text & Text \\
  \hline
    & & Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \\
  \hline  
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Code for a latex table with adjustable row height. (Credits to previous posts)

```
    \begin{table}[h]
      \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
        \hline
         col1 & col2 \\%[2ex]
        \hline
        & \\[-2ex]
        1 & 2 \\[0.75ex]
        \hline
        & \\[-2ex]
        3 & 4 \\[2ex]
        \hline
        & \\[2ex]
        5 & 6 \\[3ex]
        \hline
        & \\
        7 & 8 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image: Your table will look like this.]

Comment: Looks easier to implement for me. thank you so much