# Specify row height in a table globally

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify a fixed height for all rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/how-to-specify-a-fixed-height-for-all-rows-in-a-table)

I know that it is possible to specify the row heights of a tabular environment individually as explained in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19594/4011

However suppose I have a very large table and every row should have the same fixed height. Is it possible to change this height globally without adding something like `[2cm]` to each line?

Comment: Even though it may seem trivial, it is _always_ best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to specify a fixed height for all rows in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12761/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, I overlooked this. Perhaps we should close my question.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, then yes, we should close this one.  If you're still stuck, you can edit this question to reflect the new problem.

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `\arraystretch` command that serves as a multiplier for the row height. You can redefine it in the preamble for a global effect on all your tables.

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
```

Choose a value that fits best for you.

The [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package offers another mechanism with the `\extrarowsep` length register. But this is restricted to the environments provided by this package. For details see the package manual.

Comment: Hey, I just saw this answer. It would be great if you could elaborate on the `tabu package` solution, in order to make this answer more complete. The manual for `tabu` is quite complicated and a working example here would be great! Actually I found a working solution here: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2011-02/msg00766.html