# How to change Cell Height of table and control hline

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a need to create a table, I have shown a MWE, its producing the table with the text I want. I have two question relating to the attached image.

1. How to change the height of cells.
2. How to control the line so that it does not span across the table. my second column is 10cm and I want the line to travel only 2 cm

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{10cm}}
Heading & relavent text  \\
\hline
Alphabets & A B C D E F G .. .... .... ...  Z \\
\hline
Numbers & 1 2 3 .. .... .... .... 10 etc

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you use the `booktabs` package, turn _Heading_, _Alphabets_, and _Numbers_ into bold face text, get rid of the vertical bars, and use `\midrule` instead of `\hline`.

Comment: Marc - even `\midrule` goes from one end to other. Nothing changed I could not produce anywhere close to the attached image. Also is there anyway to keep the vertical line

Comment: The command `\cmidrule`, which is provided by `booktabs`, should let you create partial rules. It's described in the `booktabs` manual.

Comment: @Aku What results from your code is *not* like the image you show. The line extends all along the cell width (which is set to 10cm, as you state in the argument to `tabular`).

Comment: @egreg - yes the hline or midrule line extends along all the cell width.

Comment: @Aku So, what's the question? If you want that it covers only up to the widest entry, don't declare the column as `p`, but as `l`.

Comment: I have only two columns, Second column is 10 cm however I want the line to travel only 2cm as shown in the image. l declaration or P its putting the line under entire column.

Comment: @Aku I still don't understand why. Could you make a "real" example?

Comment: For modifying cell spacing/padding, see [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing this is what you are looking for second part. I don't know how to change the height of the rows. Although I found a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table) where they talk about it.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}@{}p{8cm}}
    & & \\[-\normalbaselineskip]    % Required to get the cmidrule to work.
    Heading         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{relevant text} \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
    Alphabets       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{A B C D E F G .. .... .... ...  Z} \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
    Numbers         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{1 2 3 .. .... .... .... 10 etc}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

There must be a better way than this.

Following on Harish's comment to use `arraystretch` you can do something like this,

```
\begingroup
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}@{}p{8cm}}
        & & \\[-\normalbaselineskip]    % Required to get the cmidrule to work.
        Heading         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{relevant text} \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
        Alphabets   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{A B C D E F G .. .... .... ...  Z} \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
        Numbers         & \multicolumn{2}{l}{1 2 3 .. .... .... .... 10 etc}
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
```

`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` ensure that other tables in the document are not affected.

Comment: The necessity for the "phantom line" is because otherwise all cells in the second and third columns are merged, so TeX treats them as if they were one; and this confuses the LaTeX mechanism for drawing lines across some columns only. I'd say `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` rather than `\\[-1em]`.

Comment: You can use 
`\usepackage{array}`
`\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}`
to change the row height.