# Set same height for all cells in longtable

Tags: formatting, longtable, height

I have created longtable with some text and I want set same height for all cells.

It looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{longtable}{ | p{7cm} | p{7cm} |} 
\hline
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.
&
TEXT TEXT TEXT.
\\ \hline
MORE TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
 TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
&
END.
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to set same height for all cells in table?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.ES!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question might help:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{longtable}{ | >{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][4cm]{\hsize}}p{7cm}<{\end{minipage}} | p{7cm} |} 
\hline
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.
&
TEXT TEXT TEXT.
\\ \hline
MORE TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
 TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
&
END.
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```