# Short hand for \\[space]

Tags: tables, spacing

Hi I am following the method here

[How to specify the row height in LaTeX table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table)

To increase the table row height, I was wondering is there a way to create a new command for

```
\\[space]
```

to something like `\\\` or similar so that I can change `[space]` globally?

Comment: Yes, you can set this in a number of ways. See [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764), which suggests `\extrarowheight` or `\arraystretch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow @werner 's suggestion which will effect every `tabular` environment.  Or you can define a new length:

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{3ex}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
 col A & col B & col C & \\[\mylength]
 some  & content & for & row 2
\end{tabular}
```