# How to adjust row height in table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am generating Russian table and row height issue. Below is part of my code (MWE).

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=2.1cm, inner=1cm,twoside, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{textcol}{rgb}{0,.412,.651}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{.04, .55, .87}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}\begin{longtable} {|p{3.35cm}|M{1.3cm}|M{1.87cm}|} 
\hline 
\rowcolor{textcol} \textbf{\textcolor{white} {данные}}&\textbf{\textcolor{white}{данные}}&\textbf{ \textcolor{white} {Страница}} \\ 
\endfirsthead 
\rowcolor{textcol} \textbf{\textcolor{white} {данные}}&\textbf{\textcolor{white}{данные}}&\textbf{ \textcolor{white} {Страница}} \\ 
\endhead 
\hline 
\rowcolor{rowcol} 
\parbox[t][1.058cm]{3.4cm}{\raggedright развитие постоянных зубов} & N/A&19\\ 
\hline 
\rowcolor{rowcol} 
\parbox[t][1.058cm]{3.4cm}{\raggedright ожирение (в раннем детстве)} & N/A&24\\ 
\hline 
\end{longtable}} 
\end{document}linecolor=goldenpoppy
```

[image]

In the outout, row1 of table has more height than row2 while both are using same parameter 1.058cm. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: Is this really a minimum working example (MWE)? It seems to me that a lot of packages are not necessary. What are you trying to achieve? Why not just have one table instead of two side by side? What you can do is use the `{minipage}[<vertical alignment>][<height>]{<width>}` environment inside the table cells to control the height.

Comment: Why don't you simply use *one* table?

Comment: It is part of big chunk. Actually for my need i have to use 2 side by tables. For my need, i use \parbox[t][1.058cm]{3.4cm}. How is this different from {minipage}[<vertical alignment>][<height>]{<width>}. Any working example will surely help me.

Comment: I have just updated my question. Pls refer to latest question.

Comment: The code is still far from minimal.

Comment: Does it help to specify the row height as shown here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table ?

Comment: [ex] is not suitable in my case.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the brackets in the second row. If you delet the brackets both rows have the same height. But i got no answer to this.

Comment: maybe adding `\vphantom{()}` to the row without brackets helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\begingroup%  to keep \arraystretch local
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{longtable} {|>{\RaggedRight}m{3.35cm}|M{1.3cm}|M{1.87cm}|}\hline 
 развитие\vphantom{()} постоянных зубов & N/A&19\\\hline  
 ожирение (в раннем детстве) & N/A&24\\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]