# a large table. To show entire text

Tags: tables

How can I proceed with LaTeX code such that to produce a table in which entire text to be showed normally. The photo is:

[image]

The code for last line is:

```
\hline 
VOLUMEN & $a^{3}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12}\cdot a^{3}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\cdot a^{3}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{15+ 7\sqrt{5}}}{4} \cdot a^{3}$ & $\frac{5 \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{12}\cdot a^{3}$ \\
\hline
```

Comment: Please clarify a bit, what you really want! What do you mean by entire text? Do you have problems with to narrow boxes? Please show us an MWE with documentclass and so on.

Comment: I want to see $12$, $3$, $4$ and again $12$ from denominators clearly. thanks

Comment: The output would look better if you stayed away from `\frac` , here; try writing `\sqrt{2}/12` instead `\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12}`, etc.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the `booktabs` package as it makes your table better readable and fixes your problem automatically:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rlllll}
\toprule 
POLIERDRO & CUBO & TETRAEDRO & OCTAEDRO & DODECAEDRO & ICOSAEDRO\\
\midrule
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
VERTICES & 8 & 4 & 6 & 20 & 12\\
ARTISTAS & 12 & 6 & 12 & 30 & 30\\
? & $6 \cdot a^2$ & $\sqrt{3} \cdot a^2$ & $2 \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot a^2$ & ... & ...\\
VOLUMEN & $a^3$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12}b\cdot a^3$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \cdot a^3$ & $\frac{\sqrt{15+7\sqrt{5}}}{4} \cdot a^3$ & $\frac{5 \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{12} \cdot a^3$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer to stick with your version, you have to enlarge all heights or the height of one row as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19589).

A last possibility would be to reduce the height of your equations by using a slash-notation, a `-1` exponent, decimal numbers, or packages like `xfrac` or `nicefrac`. The last two will write your fractions in slash-notation. Search this side for examples. I don't know, if these packages are still actual.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `makecell` package (to multiline centred cells and heads), `cellspace` package, to have a minimal vertical spacing at the top and borromm of cells, and `nccmath` to have medium-sized fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\rmfamily\bfseries}
\newcommand\multicolthead[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{\thead{#3}}}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{ |l|*{5}{Sc|} }
\hline
\thead*{POLIEDRO} &\thead{CUBO} & \thead{TETRAEDRO} & \thead{OCTAEDRO} & \thead{DODECAEDRO} & \thead{ICOSAEDRO} \\
\hline
CARAS & 6 cuadrados & \makecell*{4 triangulos \\equilateros} & \makecell{8 triangulos \\equilateros} & \makecell{12 pentagonos \\ regulares} & \makecell{20 triangulos \\ equilateros} \\
\hline
VERTICES &8 & 4 & 6 & 20 & 12 \\
\hline
ARISTAS & 12 & 6 & 12 & 30 & 30 \\
\hline
????? & $ 6a² $ &$ \sqrt{3}a² $ & $ 2\sqrt{3}a² $ & $ 3\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}}a² $ & $ 5\sqrt{3}a² $ \\
\hline
VOLUMEN& $a^{3}$ & $\mfrac{\sqrt{2}}{12}\cdot a^{3}$ & $ \mfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\cdot a^{3}$ & $\mfrac{\sqrt{15+ 7\sqrt{5}}}{4} \cdot a^{3}$ & $\frac{5 \sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{12}\cdot a^{3}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\def\arraystretch{1.5}` before your tabular environment to extend the height of the rows in a table. The factor in the parentheses adjusts the relative height of the rows whereas a value of `1` (or `1.0`) is default.

A good place to have it is right behind the `\begin{table}`. That way you can make shure it holds only for this particular table and not for all tables to come. Or ouy can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, respectively, to make it local.