# How to change height of rows in a table?

Tags: tables

My question is, how can I change the height of rows in my table?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7} 
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Natural number} & \textbf{Cube} \\ \hline
        1 & $1^3 = 1\times 1\times 1 = 1$  \\ \hline
        2 & $2^3 = 2\times 2\times 2 = 8$  \\ \hline
        3 & $3^3 = 3\times 3\times 3 = 27$  \\ \hline
        4 & $4^3 = 4\times 4\times 4 = 64$   \\ \hline
        5 & $5^3 = 5\times 5\times 5 = 125$  \\ \hline
        6 & $6^3 = 6\times 6\times 6 = 216$  \\ \hline
        7 & $7^3 = 7\times 7\times 7 = 343$  \\ \hline
        8 & $8^3 = 8\times 8\times 8 = 512$   \\ \hline
        9 & $9^3 = 9\times 9\times 9 = 729$  \\ \hline
        10 & $10^3 = 10\times 10\times 10 = 1000$  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must admit, that I do not know, what you want to achieve. Could you please explain what width of which row.

Comment: i want to increase width of all rows.

Comment: A row has no with. A column has a width. A row has a height. So what do you want to change?

Comment: @Manuel Weinkauf I am sorry. in fact i wanna change height. so sorry

Comment: now how can i make it coreect?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764); [How to add extra spaces between rows in `tabular` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26690/5764)

Comment: also have a look here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table

Answer (score 8):

Just modify the value of `\arraystretch`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % <--------------
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Natural number} & \textbf{Cube} \\ \hline
        1 & $1^3 = 1\times 1\times 1 = 1$  \\ \hline
        2 & $2^3 = 2\times 2\times 2 = 8$  \\ \hline
        3 & $3^3 = 3\times 3\times 3 = 27$  \\ \hline
        4 & $4^3 = 4\times 4\times 4 = 64$   \\ \hline
        5 & $5^3 = 5\times 5\times 5 = 125$  \\ \hline
        6 & $6^3 = 6\times 6\times 6 = 216$  \\ \hline
        7 & $7^3 = 7\times 7\times 7 = 343$  \\ \hline
        8 & $8^3 = 8\times 8\times 8 = 512$   \\ \hline
        9 & $9^3 = 9\times 9\times 9 = 729$  \\ \hline
        10 & $10^3 = 10\times 10\times 10 = 1000$  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any other way. just for inforamtion

Comment: You may put a `\strut` into each line.

Comment: @snehal With the `array` package, you can use `\setlength\extrarowheight{<length>}`.

Comment: @snehal With the `stackengine` package, you can apply `\addstackgap[<length>]{<any particular table cell>}`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to increase the rows height while getting the cells contents vertically centred, you can change the values of `cellspacetop/bottomlimit`, since you already use `cellspace`. Alternatively, you can load `makecell`, fix a value for `\setcellgapes` and make it effective with `\makegapedcells`.

Note the difference between both ways is that `cellspace` sets a `minimal` vertical padding at the top and bottom of the cells in columns with specifiers prefixed by the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`), whereas `makecell` *adds* a fixed vertical padding:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{makecell}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.7}

\begin{document}

\large
\begin{center}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{12pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{12pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Natural number} & \textbf{Cube} \\ \hline
        1 & $1^3 = 1\times 1\times 1 = 1$ \\ \hline
        2 & $2^3 = 2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ \\ \hline
        3 & $3^3 = 3\times 3\times 3 = 27$ \\ \hline
        4 & $4^3 = 4\times 4\times 4 = 64$ \\ \hline
        5 & $5^3 = 5\times 5\times 5 = 125$ \\ \hline
        6 & $6^3 = 6\times 6\times 6 = 216$ \\ \hline
        7 & $7^3 = 7\times 7\times 7 = 343$ \\ \hline
        8 & $8^3 = 8\times 8\times 8 = 512$ \\ \hline
        9 & $9^3 = 9\times 9\times 9 = 729$ \\ \hline
        10 & $10^3 = 10\times 10\times 10 = 1000$ \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}
%%%
\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{12pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Natural number} & \textbf{Cube} \\ \hline
        1 & $1^3 = 1\times 1\times 1 = 1$ \\ \hline
        2 & $2^3 = 2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ \\ \hline
        3 & $3^3 = 3\times 3\times 3 = 27$ \\ \hline
        4 & $4^3 = 4\times 4\times 4 = 64$ \\ \hline
        5 & $5^3 = 5\times 5\times 5 = 125$ \\ \hline
        6 & $6^3 = 6\times 6\times 6 = 216$ \\ \hline
        7 & $7^3 = 7\times 7\times 7 = 343$ \\ \hline
        8 & $8^3 = 8\times 8\times 8 = 512$ \\ \hline
        9 & $9^3 = 9\times 9\times 9 = 729$ \\ \hline
        10 & $10^3 = 10\times 10\times 10 = 1000$ \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]